# CSS styling lists

Tags: html, css, list

I have created the following and removing padding and margin but when I view in Firebug, there is a 40px I don't understand where it is coming from:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    ul{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    li{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
 <style type="text/css">
        ul{
            list-style: none;
            **margin: 0**
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-top: 0;
            padding-right: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
        }
        li{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

</style>
```

As you can see, theres a semicolon missing at

```
margin: 0
```

Just add the semicolon after that line and its fixed :)